# Release configuration -1 at startup

Tags: wxwidgets, codeblocks

I tried to compile a little program I made with Code::Blocks with the Release configuration but I get this error. Since I'm not really an expert, can somebody explain me what's happening? The Debug configuration works fine. I can't get how to fix that mismatch the log states.
Sorry if you need some code's snippets in order to help me, I can provide them if needed. Thank you!

```
#0 (    0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall() (??:??)
#1 0xb77651df   raise() (/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:??)
#2 0xb7768825   abort() (/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:??)
#3 0xb7ab03db   wxVLogFatalError (szFormat=0x80a615c L"Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.\nThe library used 2.8 (debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),\nand your program used 2.8(no debug"..., argptr=0xbffff574 "\360M\n\b|K\n\b\\O\n\b\\\301\a\b") (../src/common/log.cpp:144)
#4 0xb7ab0443   wxLogFatalError (szFormat=0x80a615c L"Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.\nThe library used 2.8 (debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),\nand your program used 2.8(no debug"...) (../src/common/log.cpp:152)
#5 (    0xb7a608f7 in wxAppConsole::CheckBuildOptions(optionsSignature=0x805edd4 "2.8 (no debug,Unicode,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6) (../src/common/appbase.cpp:427)
#6 (    0x080545a8 in ??() (??:??)
#7 0xb7aa22a6   wxEntryStart(argc=@0xbffff670: 1, argv=0x8093d88) (../src/common/init.cpp:273)
#8 0xb7aa25df   wxInitialize(argc=1, argv=0x8093d88) (../src/common/init.cpp:479)
#9 0xb7aa2750   wxInitializer(argv=0x8093d88, argc=<optimized out>, this=<synthetic pointer>) (../include/wx/init.h:81)
#10 (   wxEntry(argc=@0xb7b8f6d0: 1, argv=0x8093d88) (../src/common/init.cpp:417)
#11 0xb7aa2846  wxEntry(argc=@0xbffff6d0: 1, argv=0xbffff764) (../src/common/init.cpp:460)
#12 (   0x08052f2b in ??() (??:??)
#13 0xb77504d3  __libc_start_main() (/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:??)
#14 (   0x08053555 in ??() (??:??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your release libraries and your include files come from different versions of wxWidgets.

Try building one of the sample programs.  If that works, then you have a problem with your project configuration - you will need help from a codeblocks expert to figure that out.  If it does not work, then you have a problem with your wxWidgets installation - try getting and building a new installation.

Comment: Luckly, I just had to reinstall wxWidgets and everything worked. I was pretty sure the problem was wxWidgets-related since I share my code via Dropbox with a netbook and this one compiled the code in Release configuration without any problem. Thanks for the hint ;)